# How to reload route model from controller in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am currently struggling with a task that  I expected to be quite easy or common: I'd like to initiate a reload of the route model in the controller. As far as I can see, there is no easy way of doing this? 
Yes, I can access a `RouteInfo` object by the target property of the controller, but from there I see no way to refresh the model.

A little background about the task I try to solve:
I have a route with a model that provides the last object from a collection that has a certain flag not set (e.g. "not indexed" in route /index-object). Now the user works on this object an triggers an action in the controller which set this flag (to "indexed"). So if I reload the route by navigating back and forth the next object is shown. But I want to trigger this reload directly in the action (without reloading the whole page, of course).

My question: Is this possible or is there another/right way of accomplishing what I try to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this a bit differently. Unless the memory requirements of the data are very large you could load the entire collection in the route:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return someFunctionThatFetchesYourData();
  }
});
```

Then in your control use a computed property to filter out the item you want:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  firstObjectWithProperty: computed('model.@each.notIndexed', function(){
    return this.model.find(obj => obj.notIndexed);
  }),
});
```

Then you can just use `{{firstObjectWithProperty}}` in your template and if the `notIndexed` flag is changed it will recompute.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to tackle this. The only drawback I see: Newly created objects on the server side are not fetched. But I will go with this approach. Thanks!

Comment: True. I'm pretty sure there are some strategies for opening a web socket connection and keeping your group of objects updated with that. It would change the router slightly, but keep the controller the same.